# How to remove hidden quotes in pyspark data frame when reading it from csv file

Tags: csv, pyspark

I'm reading a csv file using pyspark in databricks.

Some columns in csv file are having ',' in them, so I have added following parameters.

```
.option("multiLine",True)        
.option('escape','"')        
.option("quote","\"")        
.option("escapeQuotes", "true")
```

I'm getting exact count with df.count() but some columns are having hidden double quotes it them. while comparing with same column from different system, they are not matching.

By looking with naked eye, they were matched, but when I copy, they are having double quotes and because of it, not able to match source and target columns.

Code I'm using for comparison:

`.filter(f"source_{c} != target_{c}"))`

[data frame view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LWfZL.png)

[having double quotes when copy to note pad](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IazIV.png)